# Gradle Not Building - Android App Bundle (.aab) in Azure DevOps

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, android-gradle-plugin, devops, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to build the Android App Bundle using the Azure DevOps task:

```
  - task: Gradle@2

    displayName: Bundle Build Project

    inputs:

      gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'

      tasks: ':$(packageName):bundleRelease'

      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'    

      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'

      testRunTitle: Bundle Build Project
```

My Project structure is as below:

```
MyAndroidFolder
 - .idea
 - customApp (Renamed the app module to customApp and using $(packageName) for this )
   - assets
   - flavors
   - libs
   - res
   - src
   - build.gradle
   (etc..)
 - gradle
 - scripts
 - azure-pipeline.yml
```

The Gradle Daemon builds the app, but the output doesn't have the aab or the $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/$(packageName)/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab

Output
[Build Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mTQP.png)

Anyhelp on this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

I'm trying to build and android app bundle from Azure DevOps using Gradle task, expecting aab file in the build/outputs/bundle/release/.aab
But when I check the artefact there's no aab file. I'm zipping the file and publishing the artefact.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a clean task after the build! My bad it took me 2 days to identify it.